# HP EliteDisplay S140u USB Monitor not working

Tags: usb, monitor

I recently switched from LM18 to Ubuntu 18.04 and am trying to work out all the bugs that come with swapping over distros.

I had an HP EliteDisplay S140u working on LM18 was able to use the driver located here (http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/file?id=1087) to do so.

When I try to install it in Ubuntu, I get the following error.

```
$ sudo '/home/dan/MEGA/DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Ubuntu 4.1/displaylink-driver-4.1.9.run'
[sudo] password for dan: 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 4.1.9  100%  
DisplayLink Linux Software 4.1.9 install script called: install
Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Installing
Configuring EVDI DKMS module
Registering EVDI kernel module with DKMS
Building EVDI kernel module with DKMS
ERROR (code 3): Failed to build evdi/4.1.9. Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/4.1.9/build/make.log for details..
```

If anyone can help me resolve this issue, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: bump...........

Answer (score 0):

There is a version 4.2 now.  I originally downloaded 4.1 (which produced the same error).  4.2 worked without a hitch.

Don't forget to `sudo apt-get install dkms`.